# Need help converting to do while loop

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I am new to programming and I have an assignment to do in C++. I need to convert this to do while loop.  Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num;
float input, sum=0, avg;

cout<<"Input the amount of numbers: ";
cin >> num; 

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
  cout<<"Enter a number: ";
  cin >> input;
  sum += input;
}

avg = sum / num;
cout << "The average is = " << avg << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and where do you get stuck? You can't ask us to complete the assignment for you.

Comment: @simon I already figured it out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple. Just put the header statements of your old `for` loop in the following places: before the new loop, in the `while` condition of the new loop, and inside the new loop as the last line of code, respectively.

Here is your old loop code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
  cout<<"Enter a number: ";
  cin >> input;
  sum += input;
}
```

And here is the new code:

```
int i = 1;
do {
  cout<<"Enter a number: ";
  cin >> input;
  sum += input;
  i++;
} while (i <= num);
```

Don't submit the assignment until you understand what I did, or you'll only be cheating yourself :) 
Check out [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_do_while_loop.htm) page for more info on a `do...while` loop. And it sounds like you could use some understanding on `for` loops as well, so check them out [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much mate :) I appreciate it.